# Visual Studio 2019 editor fails to select modules in the editor

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a problem with VS 2019 editor for a while, but it became a real problem lately.
Specifically, with the editor open, I cannot navigate to objects / classes and their methods or properties

You can see example in the screencast below.

https://www.screencast.com/t/0ceZ4C3TabY

[image: Specifically, in the]

I have the latest version, 16.10.2

This happens on two different PC's.

The problem started in a previous update, but I don't know which. I noticed it few times ago, but I didn't paid attention.

Does anyone else encountered it, and knows any solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally fixed in 16.10.3